# Animate the div text infinitely using react spring not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, slideshow

I am using the React spring library for animations and I want to infinitely animate the texts on my slides but I am unable to do that I have tried the official docs code but its saying that

```
src\Components\SlideShow.jsx
  Line 79:42:  'config' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 80:19:  'delay' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 81:40:  'config' is not defined  no-undef
```

This is the code I have written for that

```
import React from "react"
import Slider from 'react-animated-slider';
import 'react-animated-slider/build/horizontal.css';
import horizontalCss from '../Styling/SlideShow.css'
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring'
import { Keyframes } from 'react-spring/renderprops'

const slides = [
    {
        title: 'Vulputate Mollis Ultricies',
        description:
            'Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.',
        button: 'Read More',
        image: 'https://i.imgur.com/ZXBtVw7.jpg',
        user: 'Daniel',
        userProfile: 'https://s7.postimg.cc/abavelo3v/1_3x.png',
    },
    {
        title: 'Tortor Dapibus',
        description:
            'Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.',
        button: 'Discover',
        image: 'https://i.imgur.com/DCdBXcq.jpg',
        user: 'Samantha',
        userProfile: 'https://s7.postimg.cc/ujy8zz7vv/5_3x.png',
    },
    {
        title: 'Phasellus volutpat metus',
        description:
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.',
        button: 'Buy now',
        image: 'https://i.imgur.com/DvmN8Hx.jpg',
        user: 'Michael',
        userProfile: 'https://s7.postimg.cc/6exjimijv/3_3x.png',
    },
    {
        title: 'Ultricies Vulputate Mollis',
        description:
            'Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia  nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis.',
        button: 'Read More',
        image: 'https://i.imgur.com/ZXBtVw7.jpg',
        user: 'Jessica',
        userProfile: 'https://s7.postimg.cc/7ihnu80ij/4_3x.png',
    },
    {
        title: 'Odo Aenean Quam Tortor',
        description:
            'Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras mattis consectetur Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
        button: 'Discover',
        image: 'https://i.imgur.com/DCdBXcq.jpg',
        user: 'William',
        userProfile: 'https://s7.postimg.cc/f9ydt4zmj/2_3x.png',
    },
    {
        title: 'Volutpat Aenean metus',
        description:
            'quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentumconsectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis.',
        button: 'Buy now',
        image: 'https://i.imgur.com/DvmN8Hx.jpg',
        user: 'Katerina',
        userProfile: 'https://s7.postimg.cc/hsk2th5tn/6_3x.png',
    },

];
function SlideShow() {
    const props = useSpring({
        opacity: 1,
        from: { opacity: 0 },
    })
    // You can create keyframes for springs and trails
    const Container = Keyframes.Spring({
        // Single props
        show: { opacity: 1 },
        // Chained animations (arrays)
        showAndHide: [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 }],
        // Functions with side-effects with access to component props
        wiggle: async (next, cancel, ownProps) => {
            await next({ x: 100, config: config.wobbly })
            await delay(1000)
            await next({ x: 0, config: config.gentle })
        }
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Autoplay</h2>
            <Slider classNames={horizontalCss} autoplay={3000}>
                {slides.map((item, index) => (
                    <div
                        key={index}

                        style={{ background: `url('${item.image}') no-repeat center center` }}
                    >
                        <div className="center">
                        <Container state="showAndHide">{styles => <h1 className="text-center" style={styles}>{item.title}</h1>}</Container>
                            <p className="text-center">{item.description}</p>

                            <div className="text-center"><button className="btn btn-warning btn-outline-light text-dark
                            btn-lg">{item.button}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </Slider>

        </div>
    )
}
export default SlideShow;
```

Actually I want to show text by animation when the slide appears in the slide show so I've tried to do it infinitely.This is the official docs from where I've tried https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/basics.
Any help is appreciated much.Thanks